# How can I create a popup message for users to confirm Yes/No when editing the column or deleting the rows from the table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Frontend code:

```
function Home(props) {
  //make an axios request to get intents data from database
  const [intentsList, setintentsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/intents").then((response) => {
      setintentsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const updateCustomerContacted = (ID) => {
    confirm("Are you sure you want to edit?)
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
      contacted: newContacted,
      ID: ID,
    }).then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(
        customerList.map((val) => {
    alert("row updated!")
          const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
            "en-CA"
          );
          const timeStr = new Date(
            val.latest_time_of_visit
          ).toLocaleTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;

          return val.ID == ID
            ? {
                ID: val.ID,
                name: val.name,
                email: val.email,
                counts_of_visit: val.counts_of_visit,
                latest_time_of_visit: dateTime,
                contacted: newContacted,
              }
            : val;
        })
      );
    });
  };

   const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete?"))
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
      (response) => {
        alert("deleted");
        setCustomerList(
          customerList.filter((val) => {
            return val.ID != ID;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };
  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
  //page change
  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  //update contacted column
  const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

  {
    /*}
      const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/time")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setCurrentTime(data.time);
          });
      }, []);
    */
  }

  //export to csv function

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "S/N",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 100 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Information",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Email",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Counts of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 175 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Latest Time of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Contacted?",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
      ],
      data: customerList.map((val) => [
        { value: val.ID, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.latest_time_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
    },
  ];

  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          {" "}
          {/*width for different screen sizes*/}
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="danger">
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Product Statistics</h4>
                {/* <Icon>content_copy</Icon> */}
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Used Space</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                49/50 <small>GB</small>
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <BarChart />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <Danger>
                  <Warning />
                </Danger>
                <a href="#pablo" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}></a>
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="dark" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="dark">
                {/* <Store /> */}
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Locations</h4>
              </CardIcon>

              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Revenue</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>$34,245</h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Map />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <DateRange />
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        {/* <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="danger">
                            <Icon>info_outline</Icon>
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Fixed Issues</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>75</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <LocalOffer />
                            
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="info">
                            <Accessibility />
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Followers</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>+245</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <Update />
                           
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem> */}
      </GridContainer>

      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Customer Information</h4>
              {/*}
              <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                Visitors since 16th May, 2021
              </p>
                */}
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>S/n</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th>Contacted?</th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
                <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={"Previous"}
                  nextLabel={"Next"}
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  onPageChange={changePage}
                  containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                  pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
                  previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                  nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                  disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                  activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                />
                <ExcelFile
                  filename="Customer Information"
                  element={
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success float-right m-3"
                    >
                      Export to CSV
                    </button>
                  }
                >
                  <ExcelSheet
                    dataSet={DataSet}
                    name="Customer Information Report"
                  ></ExcelSheet>
                </ExcelFile>
              </div>
              {/*}
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country"]}
                tableData={[
                  ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger"],
                  ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao"],
                  ["3", "Sage Rodriguez", "$56,142", "Netherlands"],
                  ["4", "Philip Chaney", "$38,735", "Korea, South"],
                ]}
              />
            */}
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Backend code:

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//Update customers
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.body.ID;
  const contacted = req.body.contacted;

  db.query(
    "UPDATE customer_info SET contacted = ? WHERE ID = ?",
    [contacted, ID],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

//Delete customers
app.delete("/stats/delete/:ID", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.params.ID;

  db.query("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE ID = ?", ID, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//api call to pull intents data
app.get("/intents", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM data_analytics", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

Drawing reference to above front end and back end code, how can I change my code such that How can I create a popup message for users to confirm Yes/No when editing the column or deleting the rows from the table?

So I have this table, which has update and delete button, how can I add a confirmation message to it for users to select so that they have one additional layer of confirmation. How do I inform users row has been edited or deleted?

Comment: are you using any library for rendering your Table ?

Comment: I'm not using a library its a html css table

Comment: can you add your table code in the question instead of your backend ?

Comment: its in the front end

Comment: you can have a dialog which opens when you click on the delete icon . You can maintain one state for this .

Comment: How? using alert.log()?

Comment: you can use any Modal component from a library or create modal component on your own . I don't think we can customise the way alert looks or attach an event handler in the alert to take action when the user clicks on yes / or .

Comment: oh but In need the alert to have an event handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233357/discussion-between-max-and-shyam).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Material-UI for your table, you can use the [Material-UI-confirm](https://github.com/jonatanklosko/material-ui-confirm) package to handle confirmation popups for the sake of consistency. You just need to wrap your base component with their `ConfirmProvider` and use their `useConfirm` hook to display a popup message.

Also, please consider keeping only the required parts of the code in the question to make it easier for everyone to go through it.

Comment: I'm not using material UI that was just for testing

Comment: I see. In that case, you can just use the `confirm` or `window.confirm` method. It is a blocking method that displays a browser-specific popup with two options - "OK" and "Cancel", and returns a boolean. You can use this right before your Axios calls.

Comment: Ohh so just add confirm or window.confim after the update and delete methods in axios calls frontend?

Comment: If you want to prevent update/delete Axios call if the user selects "NO" in the popup, then you'll have to place it before the calls. After the call, you can use the `alert` or `window.alert` to inform the users if the row has been updated/deleted or not.

Comment: the code is window.alert("message")? like before Axios.?

Comment: I added window.confirm("Are you sure to delete?") but after I press cancel on the popup it still deletes

Comment: The `window.confirm` method returns `false` on cancellation. You can use this to stop further execution.

Comment: Even if I use Window.confirm, it still executes although I prsscancel

Comment: I used window.confirm before my delete axios calls, but I pressed cancel and the row still deletes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233387/discussion-between-kausko-and-max).